# Need help in definite integral evaluation.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I was attempting to solve a definite integral, I am stuck. First off all, I needed to evaluate this:

$-\int_0^{2\pi a}\sqrt{a^2-x^2} \;dx$.

Hence, I tried assuming,

$x=ua$ , where $u$ is some variable.

Then, differentiationg wrt $x$, we get:

$dx = a\; du$.

Then using in our initial integral, we get,

$-\int_0^{2\pi a}\sqrt{a^2-u^2a^2} \;a\;du\\[10pt]=-a\int_0^{2\pi a}a\sqrt{1-u^2}\;du\\[10pt]=-a^2\int_0^{2\pi a}\sqrt{1-u^2}\;du$.

I am stuck at this stage, I am not able to proceed forward. Can anyone help me evaluate this integral?

Comment: Try substituting $u=\sin\theta$.

Comment: The integral is undefined because it extends beyond the domain of the integrand.

Comment: @NinadMunshi So use $x/2\pi a=\sin(\theta)$

Comment: @EDX wouldn't that make it more complicated/ difficult to evaluate?

Comment: @AkashYadav then the upper and lower limit would both be equal to 0, which would result in net value of the integral as 0?

Comment: @EDX that does not fix it. At the end point the function evaluates to $\sqrt{a^2-(2\pi a)^2} = |a| \sqrt{1-4\pi^2}$ which is an imaginary number

Comment: @NinadMunshi Yes indeed ! But the result have to be complex (amybe real but complex in general) !, because $\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$ isn't real as $x>a$ which is the case in $[a,2\pi]$

Answer (score 1):

Your should cut your integral like it follows because on $[a,2\pi]$ your integrated function doesn't take real values.

$$ I=\int_0^a\sqrt{a^2-x^2}dx +i\int_a^{2\pi a}\sqrt{y^2-a^2}dy$$

Now you're able to deal with $u=x/a$ for first integral. And $y=a\cosh(u)$ for the second possible because $\cosh$ is in $[1,+\infty[$

$$ I= a^2\int_0^1\sqrt{1-u^2}du +ia^2\int_1^{\operatorname{argch}(2\pi)} (\cosh^2(u)-1)  du$$

Hence because $$ \cosh(u)^2-1=\sinh^2(u)=\dfrac{d\left(\dfrac{-x+\dfrac{1}{2}\sinh(2u))}{2}\right)}{du} $$

So:

$$ I= a^2\dfrac{1}{2}(1+\sin(1)\cos(1)+i(1-\operatorname{argch}(2\pi))+\dfrac{1}{2}(\sinh(2\operatorname{argch}(2\pi))-\sinh(2)) \ )$$

Where $$\sinh(2\operatorname{argch}(2\pi))=4\pi\sqrt{4\pi^2+1} $$

(using  $\sinh(2u)=2\cosh(u)\sinh(u)= 2\cosh(u)\sqrt{\cosh(u)^2+1} $)

And

$$ \operatorname{argch(2\pi)}=\ln(2\pi +\sqrt{4\pi^2 -1})$$

Answer (score 0):

Your integral does not make sense as it is. Note that the domain of $f(x) = \sqrt{a^{2}-x^{2}}$ is the set $\{x\in \mathbb{R}, \hspace{0.1cm} a^{2}-x^{2} \ge 0\} = \{x \in \mathbb{R},\hspace{0.1cm} -a \le x \le a\}$. Thus, $2\pi a > a$is not in the domain of the function.

Apart from that, note that if $x = ua$, we have:
$$\int\sqrt{a^{2}-x^{2}}dx = \int a^{2}\sqrt{1-u^{2}}du$$
Now, if we set $u = \sin\theta$, then $du = \cos\theta d\theta $ and $\sqrt{1-u^{2}}=\sqrt{1-\sin^{2}\theta} = \cos\theta$. Then, your integral becomes:
$$\int a^{2}\cos^{2}\theta d\theta = \frac{1}{2}a^{2}[\theta+\sin\theta\cos\theta]$$